# MySql NOT IN many values from the mysql fetched result

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 MySql queries which are interdependent.
My 'table1'

```
----------
  id
----------
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
```

My First query

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE";// some condition which gives me id's 1,2,3
$res1=$obj->_executeQuery($sql1);
$res1=$obj->getAll($res1);
```

The result of this is giving me array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            ..
            ..
        )

    [1] => Array
        (           
            [id] => 2
            ..
            ..
        )
    [2] => Array
        (           
           [id] => 3
            ..
            ..
        )
)
```

I want to run another query on same 'table1',  where not equal to list of ID's which i am getting from the first query.

My Second Query

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (" . implode(',', $res1) . ")";
```

This is not showing me only one id i,e first. In above case i should get id's 4,5,6,7

Comment: once check $res1, var dump it before you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `implode will not give` the `desired value` on `multidimensional array` so first you need to get the array of all `id's` to form `one-dimensional array` then use implode on the array of `id's`:

```
$id=array();
foreach ($res1 as $key=>$inner_array){
    $id[]= $inner_array['id'];
}
```

you can use `array_walk` also here like this:

```
array_walk($res1,function($c) use (&$id) {$id[] = $c['id'];});
```

but i think the best one is `array_map` :

```
$id = array_map(function($i) {
    return $i['id'];
}, $res1);

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (" . implode(',', $id) . ")";
```

**Note:** when ever you are doing select please specify your column if you need few to select,unnecessarily selecting all will slow your sql processing.

suppose here:`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE`, if you need only id then please select id only.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `$res1`, which is a two-dimensional array, into a one-dimensional array of IDs to be able to use `implode`:

```
$ids_from_first_query = array();
foreach($res1 as $result_row) {
    $ids_from_first_query[] = $result_row['id'];
}

$ids_as_string = implode(',', $ids_from_first_query);
$sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN(' . $ids_as_string . ')';
```

In the above code, `$ids_as_string` will look like this:

```
1,2,3
```

Thus it can be used in your MySQL query

Answer (score 0):

Here you are getting two dimensional array so that's reason it is not working

```
while($each=mysql_fetch_array($res1))
{
$array[]=$each[id];
}
$imp=implode(",",$array);
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (".$imp.")";
```

Try this it will works